# Speech (TTS) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I am using JavaScript for changing text to speech. For this purpose I use following script:

```
var Obj = new ActiveXObject("Sapi.SpVoice");
Obj.Speak(string, 1 );
```

But this is running in IE because of ActiveX, how may I run this in all other browsers?

Comment: You can't. Only IE supports SpVoice.

Comment: Is there anything which i can use for the same purpose

Comment: @DurgaDutt: Server-side processing + serving an audio file to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers based on Webkit (Google Chrome, Safari) have HTML5 `speach` input.

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

[Example](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/speech-input/index.html)

Unfortunately Firefox doesn't have such method.

There is no good cross-browser solution yet.

There is one project called [`WAMI`](http://wami.csail.mit.edu/) it work with their server side using Java applet. It may be helpful for you as java can be installed to any browser.